# Custom parameters in blog menu with own layout without messing up the sef-urls

Tags: layout, menu-parameters

Just recently, I started working on a project in which I needed to add blog-menus in which I have to add custom parameters (for further filtering of the articles on the frontend).

I've added a projects.xml and projects.php in my template inside the html/com_content/category/ directory and added the custom fields there (a couple of list fields).
The projects.php works as my template.

But, there is one huge problem:
If I create a menu item, name the thing and fill out the fields (let's say they are called "category" and "subcategory"), everything works, but the url gets messed up, since the newly created parameters are added at the end as query parameters like this:

```
https://www.domainname.com/menu-item?category=value1&subcategory=value2
```

Anyone know how to prevent this? All I want is to use these parameters (I cannot use Joomla-categories here, so I absolutely need to use something like this), but while at the same time having a clean url like this:

```
https://www.domainname.com/menu-item
```

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Never mind, this is a Joomla 4 bug (in J3 it worked without issues), you even cannot add tag filters in a blog-menu item without getting the ugly query-string, an issue about it is open for nearly two years on github.
This is ridiculous for such a large project.